# CPU Process time using GetProcessTimes and FileTimeToSystemTime do not work in 64 bit win

Tags: c++, windows, 32bit-64bit, cpu-time

I am trying to measure CPU time.
It works great on Win 32, but on 64 bit, it says:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetProcessTimes referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl getWINTime(void)" (?getWIN32Time@@YAIXZ)
```

It has similar error for `FileTimeToSystemTime`

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_FileTimeToSystemTime referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl getWINTime(void)" (?getWIN32Time@@YAIXZ)
```

Function itself is not that important there is no issue with it.
Are this calls legit in 64 bit architecture or what?

This is not the only issue it seems like its not linking correctly to libraries on 64 bit windows.
Is there a setting I should set for it to link properly?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue on a 64bit build in Visual Studio 2008.  The functions are valid in a 64bit world..so could you post up some code/and/or give a bit more for us to work with?

Comment: it turned out it was using environment variable and linking to 32 bit version of libs instead of 64 bit...thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you're build settings for the two environments have the same import libraries listed. Both of those functions are in kernel32.dll.

Comment: kernel32 is in the part of inherited values in Additional Dependencies in project settings

Comment: This should be accurate.  Prove it to yourself by adding another kernel32 function to your code.  Like IsDebuggerPresent().

Answer (score 1):

Check your linker flags. The entire project configuration for 64-bit builds is different from that of 32-bit builds. So check your project settings to verify that they both link to the same libraries.

Also check that the compiler and linker got invoked correctly, either by checking the Command Line panes in project settings, or by inspecting the build log.

I just tried creating a 64-bit build of this code in Visual Studio 2010, and it worked fine:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  __in  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  __in  int nCmdShow
) {
  FILETIME ct;
  FILETIME et;
  FILETIME kt;
  FILETIME ut;
  GetProcessTimes(NULL, &ct, &et, &kt, &ut);

  SYSTEMTIME st;
  FileTimeToSystemTime(&ut, &st);

}
```

I simply created a new Win32 project, added a 64-bit platform, and compiled. I didn't change any project settings at all.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for GetProcessTimes and FileTimeToSystemTime will tell you the headers to include, AND the library file to link to as well. However, Visual studio will usually link those in for you automatically.
Do you have ignore default libraries checked perhaps in your project?